Performing Left Join for Tables generated Using diesel-dynamic-schema
macro_rules! makeTable {
    ($a:expr, $b:expr) => {
        schema($a).table($b)
    };
}

pub fn testLeftJoin (conn: &mut PgConnection) -> () {
    use diesel::query_dsl::JoinOnDsl;

    let tableA = makeTable!("public", "tableA");
    let tableB = makeTable!("public", "tableB");

    let requestIdA = tableA.column::<SqlT::Varchar, _>("requestId");
    let requestIdB = tableB.column::<SqlT::Varchar, _>("requestId");

    let idB = tableB.column::<SqlT::Varchar, _>("id");

    let query = tableA
                .left_join(tableB.on(requestIdA.eq(requestIdB)))
                .select(idB)
                .load(conn);
    ()
}


44 |                 .left_join(tableB.on(requestIdA.eq(requestIdB)))
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `SingleValue` is not implemented for `NotSelectable`, which is required by `SelectStatement<FromClause<diesel_dynamic_schema::Table<&str, &str>>>: InternalJoinDsl<_, LeftOuter, _>`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `SingleValue`:
             CChar
             Cidr
             Citext
             Double
           and 78 others
   = note: required for `NotSelectable` to implement `IntoNullable`
   = note: required for `NullableExpression<diesel_dynamic_schema::dummy_expression::DummyExpression>` to implement `diesel::Expression`
   = note: 1 redundant requirement hidden
   = note: required for `(diesel_dynamic_schema::dummy_expression::DummyExpression, NullableExpression<diesel_dynamic_schema::dummy_expression::DummyExpression>)` to implement `diesel::Expression`
   = note: required for `(diesel_dynamic_schema::dummy_expression::DummyExpression, NullableExpression<diesel_dynamic_schema::dummy_expression::DummyExpression>)` to implement `AppearsOnTable<query_source::joins::Join<diesel_dynamic_schema::Table<&str, &str>, diesel_dynamic_schema::Table<&str, &str>, LeftOuter>>`
   = note: required for `query_source::joins::Join<diesel_dynamic_schema::Table<&str, &str>, diesel_dynamic_schema::Table<&str, &str>, LeftOuter>` to implement `QuerySource`
   = note: 1 redundant requirement hidden
   = note: required for `JoinOn<Join<Table<&str, &str>, Table<&str, &str>, LeftOuter>, Grouped<Eq<Column<Table<&str, &str>, &str, Text>, Column<Table<&str, &str>, &str, Text>>>>` to implement `QuerySource`
   = note: required for `SelectStatement<FromClause<diesel_dynamic_schema::Table<&str, &str>>>` to implement `InternalJoinDsl<diesel_dynamic_schema::Table<&str, &str>, LeftOuter, diesel::expression::grouped::Grouped<diesel::expression::operators::Eq<diesel_dynamic_schema::Column<diesel_dynamic_schema::Table<&str, &str>, &str, diesel::sql_types::Text>, diesel_dynamic_schema::Column<diesel_dynamic_schema::Table<&str, &str>, &str, diesel::sql_types::Text>>>>`

I am trying to make the table name on runtime with the help of the diesel-dynamic-schema crate. so i made a macro which calls the relevant functions and makes a table for the input schema and table name. Now, with that i want to do a left join on two tables. like shown in the snippet, i make two tables, link the columns i would be using for the join.
However this join fails. i get error for left_join which is shown below.
